# Obtain database data into fixture files

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm

does anyone know if there is anyway to obtain the data from an oracle database into fixtures files? Even using any symfony2 method or bundle?

PD: I'm working with the latest stable symfony2 version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use: https://github.com/symfony/DoctrineFixturesBundle and implement `ContainerAwareFixture`, then you should have access to your Oracle connection.